# Google translate thinks my language is French because I have a .fr url

Tags: google-translate

I have a blog at http://krugerparktrip.blogspot.fr/ and have added the Widget, Google Translate. It thinks my text is French, which it is not and as a consequence, the language option drop down list leaves French out. If I click on English in the list and then check the list again French is there. Is there a way round this?

Comment: Sue google or apparently change top-level-domain

Comment: Hey, I just found out, that when adding the `Plug-in` to your website, you can choose the *original language*: http://translate.google.com/manager/website/add?hl=en. On blogspot you perhaps were not able to do that? Or how have you added the `blogspot.com-plug-in`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself!  The problem so often is that the developer changes where they put things and some older advices were no longer valid.

Go to Settings and Language and change the language to English. It was set to French and it thinks the text (although in English) is French. Doh!!!